# Remove Warning- QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onValueChanged"

Tags: qt, qml

My code runs fine as expected but why do I get the warning messsage:

```
QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onValueChanged"
```

Here is how I linking to signal.

```
Connections {
    target: myModel
    onValueChanged: {
        console.log("Valued changedRecieved in QML")
    }
```

myModel is a C++ class that I am exposing to QML using `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", &model);`

Is there a way to remove this warning?

Comment: Does your model have a `valueChanged` signal? Because `QAbstractItemModel` doesn't.

Comment: Yes it does and and qml code does catch that signal and process it but its the warning message which is annoying.

Comment: When does the message appear?

Comment: @cmannett85 When I run the application

Comment: Yeah I figured that. I meant do you see it at startup, when performing a particular action, or at application shutdown?

Comment: Maybe is printed initially when the qml is loaded and you export myModel only afterwards?

Comment: You should show us your `main.cpp`; you'd probably have had an answer by now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your Connections scope just set **ignoreUnknownSignals: true**